# how to get var from other classes

Tags: java, android, eclipse, class

I believe I have a simple question.... but for me as beginner, I can't see it anymore.

In a class I want to get some var's from another class.

class 1:

```
package com.blabla;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //get shared preferences

    GetSettings test1 = new RingSettings();
    String theSMStext = test1.getSMStext();
    Boolean theActivateSMS = test1.getActivateSMS();    
}
}
```

class 2:

```
package com.blabla;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
public class GetSettings {

/**
 * @param args
 */
private String SMStext;
private Boolean ActivateSMS;


public static void RingSettings(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    String SMStext = sp.getString("SMStext", "0");
    Boolean ActivateSMS = sp.getBoolean("ActivateSMS", false);
}

public String getSMStext(){
    return SMStext;
}

public Boolean getActivateSMS(){
    return ActivateSMS;
}
}
```

Eclipse is giving me in class1 "RingSettings can't resolved to a type" => at GetSettings test1 = new RingSettings();

What I'm doing wrong?!

Comment: Unless you have a class somewhere called `RingSettings` right now you're trying to instantiate a method `RingSettings`, from the class `GetSettings` which will obviously fail. I recommend you to learn a bit more about Java(and Android as well). Also maybe you wanted to do `GetSettings test1 = new GetSettings();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitly have a few things to fix here.

- RingSettings as defined in GetSettings returns type void not a GetSettings object.
- RingSettings is defined to take a context as an argument.
- RingSettings is defined as a method of a GetSettings object and should be called with GetSettings.RingSettings(context)
- assuming you are trying to create a GetSettings object... GetSettings should have a constructor

These are just a few to get started.  I don't mean to be rude here but you should be playing with some simpler examples to better learn the basics of Java.  That being said, if you fix the above problems and repost your code someone should be able to get you closer to what your trying to accomplish.

Check out this info on the `new` keyword: (to get you started)

[The new operator instantiates a class by allocating memory for a new object and returning a reference to that memory. The new operator also invokes the object constructor.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is implementing a helper class:

```
public class GlobalVars extends Application {

    private static String value2;


    public static String getValue() {
        return value2;
    }

    public static void setValue(String value) {
        value2 = value;
    }
}
```

In class A set the value as `GlobalVars.setValue("something");`

In class B get the value as `String your_value = GlobalVars.getValue();`

Comment: Unfortunately this does nothing to solve the errors in this code. It only adds yet another level of complexity.

Comment: This answer worked perfectly for me when, combined with the other answers and comments regarding manifest entries.